# Wordpress: Display content from a Custom Post Type within a regular Post

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I feel like there is a really simple solution to this problem. However, after trying to solve it for about 3 hours unsuccessfully, I humbly come to you.

#### The Basics:

- A custom post type, " ***band*** ", has been created, and has several
  custom fields (which were created through the [Advanced Custom
  Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)
  plugin.)

#### The Question:

How would I get and display the contents (specifically custom field data) of a specific ***band*** entry (using its *ID* or *title* or *slug*) *inside* of a regular post? (see [diagram](http://thisnewband.com/images/diagram.png) below)

[image: this diagram]
<sub>(source: [thisnewband.com](http://thisnewband.com/images/diagram.png))</sub>
.

#### Methods to Trigger the Display of the Custom Post Type:

*We have to provide the ID/title/slug so that it knows what* ***band*** *post's content to display*

- Shortcode (such as `[band id="21"]` ) (*added inside post content*)
- Custom Field (custom field name `band-id` where you can input the ID of the ***band***)

#### What I've Tried and Why It Didn't Work:

1. Shortcode

   - `[band id="21"] inserted in post editor field
   - Used `WP_Query` to query post with *type*=***band*** and *ID*="21".
   - Code located in `functions.php`
   - Result: It would echo static text but would not display any post-specific content (Band Name, etc.). Also would not pull post-specific custom field data.
   - (also tried `query_post` with no luck)
2. Custom Field

   - Entered ID (21) into custom field on post editor page.
   - Coded it directly into the post template:

     - Used `WP_Query` and had the `ID` in the array pull from the custom field.
   - Result: Nothing good happened.

#### Where I Keep Running Into Trouble:

- It's hard to pull the custom field data from the custom post type while inside an actual post

#### The Optimal Solution:

Whether it's by using a shortcode, custom field, or even a new widget, it would be easiest if one could:

1. Create a PHP template with the code for just how the single ***Band*** content is supposed to display. (Including the loop). Example name: *band-block.php*
2. Use `get_template_part('band-block');` to echo this code (either in Post Template or Shortcode via *functions.php*)

Thanks for your help! Let me know if you'd like to see any of my code.

Comment: Your shortcode approach looks like it should work.  How are you retrieving the post-specific content?  Are you providing the band ID as the second argument to [the_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/) (or [get_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some amazing help from [Hobo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714/hobo), I was able to come up with a solution!

**The main problem** was with trying to query by 'ID'. No matter what we tried, it just never worked well. (It could be the way that the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) stored the ID field contents.)

#### What did work:

1. Created a custom field for the post page in which to put the ***Band*** *(custom post type)* post name/slug into. (Custom field was named `post-band-name` and created with the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin.)
2. Placed the query code in the Post Template. (See code below)
3. Done.

### [The Solution Code](http://pastebin.com/p5dKvk7e)

Answer (score 1):

I knew you have found a solution for your problem, but for others i will give them an other solution:

You can query by ID, no problem. Look at these: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/relationship/
But you have to check in the custom field "return format" the box "Post IDs". Then it works perfectly well.

Sorry for my bad english ;)
Cheers

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add this loop after the normal loop...

```
<?php /* Display all the author's posts from the custom post type ('band') */ ?>
<?php
    $authorid = get_the_author_meta( ID, $userID );
           $args4=array('author'=>$authorid,'post_type'=>'band', 'numberposts'=> -1);
           $cquery4=new WP_Query($args4);
           if($cquery4->have_posts()):
               while($cquery4->have_posts()):
                   $cquery4->the_post();
           ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
               <p><?php the_title();?></p>
</a>
           <?
               endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
           endif;
?>
```